# SVN Branching pattern for Multiple Projects / Modules

Tags: svn, version-control

After reading up on the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) I am trying to cleanup the structure of my SVN repository. [Chapter 4 - Branching & Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout) talks about using the trunk, branch and tags layout for multiple projects.

In my scenario, I have multiple modules (libraries, plugins, and vendor libs) that I maintain for a series of projects. Not one of the projects uses all of the modules, but each module is used by at least one project.

1. Can I create a branch for each project that references individual module versions? It seems like [Complex Tagging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html#svn.branchmerge.tags.mkcomplex) is the answer to this...
2. How could I use [Complex Tagging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html#svn.branchmerge.tags.mkcomplex) as a baseline for a project team?
3. What would the workflow be for a software engineering to checkout / modify / commit a project? e.g A member from Team Rocket wanted to add a new feature to the Fred plugin. (see below for layout)
4. Should initial changes be made on a feature branch of the module or the project?

Ultimately I would like to see the following repository structure:

```
-Library
| -libFoo
| | -trunk
| | -branch
| | -tags
| |
| -libBar
| | -trunk
| | -branch
| | -tags
| |
| -plugins
|   -pluginFred
|   | -trunk
|   | -branch
|   | -tags
|   | 
|   -pluginBarney
|     -trunk
|     -branch
|     -tags
|
-Projects
  -Galactic
  | -trunk
  | -branch
  | -tags
  |
  -Rocket
    -trunk
    -branch
    -tags
```

~regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create a branch for each project that references individual module versions?

Yes.

> It seems like Complex Tagging is the answer to this

It's *can be* answer, but from my POV it will be dirty way. If any of your project have to have as part of it's tree *some known state* of *some modules* also SVN-versioned, I'll prefer to use [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) (directory-type) with externals-sources mapped to needed|wanted version of module. It can be revision-less definition with URL for module's tag|branch (not good but possible for commitable branch, OK for RO tag), or [PEG-revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) for *any* URL of any module

> How could I use Complex Tagging as a baseline for a project team?

I'll suggest "nohow". Complex tag is good as temporary hack, but bad from historical perspective - you will not be able to reconstruct "how and from which sources this mixed WC was created before committing", contrary to (fully PEG-ged) WC with externals to all used modules

> What would the workflow be for a software engineering to checkout / modify / commit a project? e.g A member from Team Rocket wanted to add a new feature to the Fred plugin.

Well, my initial reaction was "It depends", next: "Too broad". Really it's more management's and administrative question, than technical and dependent from humans than from technology (and have a lot of variations). In short (in ideal nice world):

- TR Dev branching pluginFred, modify, test, merge branch to pluginFred's trunk, test again
- Team Rocket PM accept these changes and agree to use modified pluginFred
- External definition(s) for pluginFred in Team Rocket project (at some revision) changed from URL@OLDREV to URL@NEWREV (or from `pluginFred/**/URL1` to `pluginFred/**/URL2`)
- Other teams are also informed by *some way* and switch (or not) to new version

Good (fast and bullet-proof) communication in (and between) teams is the hardest part of work. No comminication and PEG-less externals to WIP is direct way to chaos and developer's hell

> Should initial changes be made on a feature branch of the module or the project?

"It depends"... from habits, ACLs, company's rules, repository's tree and cross-repositories project's separations (for single monolithic repo you can svn copy from any location to any at any time, cross-repo transfers are slightly harder, but still possible). But in common "What's the difference?", **if you have full traceable history** (and if you have not - you must to have)

Comment: +1 Thanks for this extremely detailed approach. I need to further digest all the details that it is you are suggesting but from a high level perspective this seems like a solid approach. Thank You again.